# how to refresh the list in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I have to implement the share product functionality with the user after share  i have to refresh the  list here selectedSharedIntermediaryInAlbum is our array so how to implement this?

```js
//refreshSharedIntermediary for refresh the lsit
$scope.refreshSharedIntermediary = function() {
  $scope.selectedSharedIntermediaryInAlbum = $scope.selectedSharedIntermediaryInAlbum; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="w3-right">
    <button class="btn btn-rose btn-sm" tltle="refresh data" ng-click="refreshSharedIntermediary()">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: how is `selectedSharedIntermediaryInAlbum` used? what form is updating it?

Comment: selectedSharedIntermediaryInAlbum  is an array of the shared user?

Comment: You are not clear about "refreshing" it. Do you want to update some values (users) in that array? If so, then how are you doing it? Is there an input form that you fill in?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$scope.reload function` where need to reload the list ... i have used below concept :

```
<div class="well well-lg" ng-repeat="item in list track by item.id">
  <button class="btn btn-default" 
          ng-click="collapsedFlags[item.id] = !collapsedFlags[item.id]">
    {{ item.isCollapsed ? '+' : '-' }}
  </button>
  <div uib-collapse="collapsedFlags[item.id]" ng-bind="item.value"></div>
</div>

$scope.reload = function () {
  $http.get('list.json').then(function (data) {
    $scope.list = data && data.data || [];
  });
};

$scope.collapsedFlags = {};

$scope.reload();
```

Working example : https://plnkr.co/edit/87vVb8Jjyz6yFGAjiHBK?p=preview

Comment: sir after refresh the list data is same as a JSON ..but in my case list is repeated multiple times?

Comment: pls Share the working example link so that can provide the solution